# Need to assign object id to field when creating object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got an object that has a property which, on creation, should always be populated with the object's id(primary key).

How do I do that?

I've tried assigning the id to the field just after the db savechanges(), before returning to the view, but that creates two records on my db.

Also tried loading a new instance of the same, assign the id to the field and save it, but also creates two records.

Thanks for any help.

```
//model
public partial class supplier
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int ref { get; set; }
}
//controller
public ActionResult Create(supplier sup)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.suppliers.add(sup)
        db.SaveChanges();

        sup.ref = sup.id;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    ...
}
```

Hi all, thanks for all your help... I've found a solution... don't really know if it's the correct one, but it does the job.

For whoever is interested here it is:

```
supplier needToUpdateSupplier = (from s in db.suppliers where s.id.Equals(supplier.id) select s).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
if (needToUpdateSupplier != null)
{
    needToUpdateSupplier.ref = supplier.id;
    db.suppliers.Attach(needToUpdateSupplier);
    db.Entry(needToUpdateSupplier).Property(e => e.ref).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This question needs a little more detail. How are you saving your data to the database? Are you using Entity Framework, etc.?

Comment: sorry, yes I'm using EF... not a C# developer either...

Comment: Why do you have it referencing itself?  What value does this add to the relationships that are in the database or in the application?

Comment: Hi @Justin this is a legacy system. I need that field to be created with the suppliers id by default. What happens later I don't really care. I know it doesn't make sense, but that's what I have to do. I do appreciate you pointing flaws in the design, and please, don't get me wrong, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Let's just say I want to update my newly created object right after it was created. It doesn't matter if I'm trying to attribute the object's id to some property... it could be any value.

Comment: @user2881726 Will this "ref" value ever be used with in your application?  Will users be able to change it?  What database engine are you using?  I ask these questions to give you the best solution to match your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the object
2. Save it (SaveChanges). This will give you the id.
3. Assign the id to your property, using the existing object (you don't need to load it again)
4. Save again

Notes: The property must be nullable, because up on creation it will be empty.

```
// A Test object
class MyObject
{
    public int ID {set;get;}
    public int? MyProperty {set;get;}
}

void Foo()
{
    var test = new MyObject();
    db.MyObjects.Add(test);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // at this moment test has the Id set. You can assign it.

    test.MyProperty = test.Id;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: hi... thanks for your answer but I've tried that... If I use dbcontext.savechanges() twice, it creates two records... I've just tried setting the state to modified before the second savechanges() but still doing the same.

Comment: There is something wrong in your model or the code you are using. Please provide some code of the model and method.

Comment: You can edit your question to add it there, it can also be formatted. Your code seems fine. Please add the `supplier` class code. Make sure the Id is not nullable and unique (use the EF attributes for this)

Comment: sorry... I don't know how to add formatted code... I'm trying different markups from the documentation but it doesn't work...

Comment: While editing, select the block of code in the question and click the toolbar icon with the two braces `{}`

Comment: there u go... edited my question... many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: As said before, you should set ref as nullable `int?`

Comment: Hi Odys, I already found a solution(it's in my post) but thanks for answering back. The ref field was populated with a default value anyway when it was first created. Thanks again.

Comment: If you change its type to `int?` the problem is gone. It takes zero because its not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

With EF it should set the ID for you:

```
db.Posts.Add(post);
db.SaveChanges();

// post.ID should be now set
```

Comment: If the field is configured to be Identity.